# Upload file by sendkeys in python opens a file selector popup

Tags: python, selenium, firefox, sendkeys, headless

The component which needs to be automated is antd - upload.

```
https://ant.design/components/upload/ --> Can be found here
```

The button for the upload is visible, but the input "tag" is not visible:

Component view: [This is the button how it is seen on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NDeRE.png)

HTML view: [This is the view of the inspection of the component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QF8q3.png)

As you see the "input" is not visible.

To have selenium interact with the input (to use the sendkeys) I need to have the input element visible on the screen.

I make an execute script as follows:

```
file_input = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath)
self.driver.execute_script('arguments[0].style.display = "block"; ', file_input)
```

After this I get the following view of the component: [component ui view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4aLK.png)

And the html view: [HTML view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfvh5.png)

After this I interact with the component by sending keys to the element:

```
file_input.send_keys(fpath)
```

At this step I have 2 things happening: 
1. **the file selector popup is shown** 
2. **the file is uploaded by the send_keys.**

This causes an issue when I try to run the scripts in headless browser. The message that is shown:

```
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: Tried to run command without establishing a connection headless browser
```

This is only due to running in headless browser mode. When the browser is displayed, the scripts are kept going. I have also tried using on both displayed and headless browser the module pyautogui:

```
pyautogui.keyDown('esc')
pyautogui.keyUp('esc')
```

This helps only on the displayed browser, so the popup is closed. But for headless browser this doesn't help.

I am running the scripts on MacOS Sierra, Firefox (58.0.2) in headless browser options, python 2.7, selenium 3.8

Would be very grateful if someone knows how to work around this.

Thank you

Comment: What happens when you're not making the input element visible. It's my experience that it is possible to execute the sendkey command without making the input visible first.

Comment: @Frank when trying to send keys with out making the input element visible I get: ElementNotInteractableException: Message: Element <input type="file"> is not reachable by keyboard

Comment: With Chromedriver this is no problem. See the discussion here: https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/1173

Comment: @Frank, Have updated my latest ChromeDriver and Chrome and now I am able to run fully what I need without having the pop-up come up. Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

Update with the latest chromedriver and chrome. This is working without having a popup come out for headless browser when running this step by send-keys in selenium.

Firefox still has this issue with geckodriver.